# sortable jquery list not working in IE 9.0 after hiding sibling div node

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's the code I'm trying to fix: http://jsfiddle.net/fabKu/.

Everything works just fine until you hide ( use the buttons ) the second div.
The code works in every other major browser, only IE causes trouble.

I've no idea why is this happening, so I'm asking for a little help.

EDIT:

Here's a detailed explanation of the problem. It`s all about indexes.

**Environment:**

Browser: IE 9.0

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Hide the second div. ( click the first button )
2. Try to move the 15th item ( for example ) on position 7 ( for example ).

**Current behavior:**

The index of the 15th item is change to "02" ( during drag ) and when you place it in the new position the ordering is mixed up.

**Expected behavior**

Reload the page and do the same thing but without hiding the second div.

**Workaround**

One possible workaround is to place a new div between the first and the second one. IE seems to be having problems with the reindexing if the node after the div containing the "ol" node have "display" set to "none". ( seems it does not matter if the node is a div or something else )

Comment: Please expand this question... what does not work as expected.

Comment: By "index" do you mean the number at the beginning or the number it says after item?

Comment: This "problem" is a non-issue in IE7 BTW, since it does not even show the prefixed item number.

Comment: 1) I'm only interested in IE 9.0 2) You are right, my explanation of the problem was very poor - sorry. By index I mean the the number before "Item ".

Comment: I believe this is a CSS issue, it might be a jQuery bug.

Comment: I've updated the original question with a workaround. I still have no idea what causes the wrong reindexing, but if I find out I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I have verified the following works in IE7 with this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Agwp2/1/

Try this:

```
                $('form input:eq(0)').click( function()
                {
                    $('#divToHide').hide();
                });

                $('form input:eq(1)').click( function()
                {
                    $('#divToHide').show();
                });
```

If that works in IE then the problem is with incompatible CSS.

Comment: No, this does not works.
From what I read in the jQuery docs, .hide() is almost exactly what I do with the .hidden class.

Comment: So when you use this code in ie it does not work -- that is, it does not hide the content?

Comment: @user931392 - Isn't that the point, you have a bug.  jQuery is doing the functionality with cross browser code tested by millions of people.  Maybe their code does not have a bug.  Using their code you can leverage all that testing and have a cross browser site.

Comment: I`m using IE 9.0, that`s the target browser. The fix you proposed does not work there. You can see that the ordering still gets messy after a few reorders. ( Another thing is that the index of the element currently dragged is changed to "02." when you start dragging )

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  All the question says is about hide/show.  Please update the original question with the *actual* problems you are having otherwise no one will be able to help.